# mysql creating table - PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, create-table

Problem getting this to work:

I am putting this query string (as a variable):

```
"query" => 
            "CREATE TABLE 
                users(
                    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY,
                    date_created DATETIME,     
                    last_active DATETIME,
                    last_logged_in DATETIME,
                    first_name VARCHAR(255),
                    last_name VARCHAR(255),
                    email VARCHAR(255), 
                    password VARCHAR(255),  
                    permissions INT,  
                    status SMALLINT
                )"
```

into this loop:

```
foreach( $queryStrings as $queryString )
{  
    $query = Database::Query( $queryString[ "query" ] );
    if( $query )
    {
        echo "Database table " . $queryString[ "name" ] . " successfully created<br />"; 
    }
    else
    {     
        echo "Database table " . $queryString[ "name" ] . " failed to create<br />"; 
    }
}
```

The Database:Query is here:

```
    public static function Query( $query )
    {
        $query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( trim( $query ) );  

        if ( $query = self::$mysqli->prepare($query) ) 
        {
            $query->execute();   

            $DatabaseQuery = new DatabaseQuery();
                $DatabaseQuery->result = $query->get_result();       
                $DatabaseQuery->mysql_num_rows = $query->num_rows();                 
                $query->close();
                return $DatabaseQuery;                   
        }          

        echo false;
    }
```

It fails to get past:

```
if ( $query = self::$mysqli->prepare($query) )
```

The string it is preparing is here:

```
CREATE TABLE \r\n users(\r\n id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,\r\n date_created DATETIME, \r\n last_active DATETIME,\r\n last_logged_in DATETIME,\r\n first_name VARCHAR(255),\r\n last_name VARCHAR(255),\r\n email VARCHAR(255), \r\n password VARCHAR(255), \r\n permissions INT, \r\n status SMALLINT\r\n )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove the `\r` and `\n` from the query string using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
 $string = str_replace(array("\n", "\r"), '', $string);
```

Or you could do the same with [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\r\n]/', '', $string);
```

Comment: Meant to when you did it but I couldn't because I had to wait 4 mins. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

Of course removing linefeed characters is a wrong answer.

It's whole `$query = self::$mysqli->real_escape_string( trim( $query ) );` line should be removed instead, as it's shouldn't be used on the whole query in general and practically useless for the prepared queries like this one.